# Kivy. How to select different mouse devices. How to create an event 'on move'

Tags: python, python-2.7, input, mouse, kivy

Most of my previous experience is in embedded so I guess I am very lacking in OOP.

So far here is a dry run using kivy's framework :

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window


class MyWidget(Widget):
    def my_on_motion (self, something_missing_here, my_motion_event):

        print my_motion_event.pos  , my_motion_event.device      

        pass

    Window.bind(on_motion=my_on_motion)          


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

I wanted to build a puzzle mechanics with a "hover over to select" sort of Mechanics
using multiple plug and play 'standalone touchpads'.

Effectively I have 2 questions:

- How do I differentiate between device id's?
  (in this case 'device' is always 'mouse' irrespective of plugging multiple mouses)
- How do I get the motion event to trigger on movement of the mouse, not just when touch is True?

Comment: I guess what I m looking for is could I have a RAWINPUT from each device separately ?

Comment: You can bind to Window.mouse_pos to get cursor position regardless of clicks, but I'm not sure how to deal with multiple inputs. It's undoubtedly possible, and possibly not too hard, but probably someone on kivy's irc or mailing list would have a better idea of how to do so.

Comment: Briliant @inclement! I have seen many of your contributions here, thanks a lot for supporting kivy questions in SO. I guess I will divide in small chunks i.e. I will get the basics to work from one touchpad and then investigate it further once I start to get some air under the wings. For reference I will just write an ELI5 explicit solution "Window.bind(mouse_pos=my_on_motion)" :)